# Symfony2 form hierarchical checkboxes

Tags: forms, symfony, checkbox

is there anyway to make a hierarchical checkboxes form element?

I have my Doctrine entity "Tax" that can have a parent.

And in a form I have defined this field that references taxes.

```
$builder->add('impuestos', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'MyBundle:Tax',
            'label' => 'Taxes',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true));
```

I was looking on Google and seeing the Symfony docs and source and I can't figure how can I display this field in a hierarchical way.

I what I need is somthing like this:

```
[] Parent Tax 1
-- [] Child 1 of parent tax 1
-- [] Child 2 of parent tax 1
[] Parent Tax 2
-- [] Child 1 of parent tax 2
-- [] Child 2 of parent tax 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but see http://shout.setfive.com/2014/10/24/symfony2-outputting-form-checkboxes-in-a-hierarchy/ (not my link) for the answer.  I'm still trying to figure out how to do three layers deep...